# In large part... in small part

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

What is the "conjunction" for in large part?

For example:

> Items in this category were in large part based on Doyle and Stern’s
>   (2006) definitions of globalization, and in small part based on
>   Levitt’s (1983) notion of globalization.

Is this correct?

Comment: Combining the two idioms is unusual at best.

Comment: Items in this category were in large part based on Doyle and Stern’s (2006) definitions of globalization, and, *to a lesser extent,*  [based] on Levitt’s (1983) notion of globalization. (Also omit the second "based".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not correct.  Saying "and in a small part" is rather odd (as you are duplicating part) and probably isn't what you mean.

I think I'd say "..in large part.." or perhaps "largely based on" and then follow it up with a "to a smaller extent".

Alternatively "largely items in this category" and then "and also" or "perhaps also"

If I had to rewrite it I'd say (although I'm not sure if it is true)..

"Items were initially defined to be in this category by X and the definition was later expanded/reduced (to include or exclude whatever items are now deemed or not deemed to be in the category) by Y."